# MySQL: How to add the result of two fields created in the current select statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a MySQL View table, so my code looks something like this so far:

```
CREATE VIEW `myview`
AS SELECT
    (do some stuff here) AS `Revenue1`,
    (do some more here)  AS `Revenue2`
FROM ...
```

Now I want to add a column that is the sum of both of those fields, so I tried this:

```
CREATE VIEW `myview`
AS SELECT
    (do some stuff here) AS `Revenue1`,
    (do some more here)  AS `Revenue2`,
    (`Revenue1` + `Revenue2`) AS `TotalRevenue`
FROM ...
```

but this resulted in an error saying that the `Revenue1` field was unknown. How can I add the two fields and get the result as a new column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must repeat the stuff as:

```
CREATE VIEW `myview`
AS SELECT
    (do some stuff here) AS `Revenue1`,
    (do some more here)  AS `Revenue2`,
    ((do some stuff here) + (do some more here)) AS `TotalRevenue`
FROM ...
```

or create a second view as:

```
CREATE VIEW `myview_Two`
AS SELECT
    `Revenue1`,
    `Revenue2`,
    `Revenue1` + `Revenue2` AS `TotalRevenue`
FROM myview
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
CREATE VIEW `myview` 
AS 
  SELECT 
       (do some stuff here) AS `Revenue1`,     
       (do some more here)  AS `Revenue2`,     
       (do some stuff here) + (do some more here) AS `TotalRevenue`
  FROM ...
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206062/mysql-view-with-subquery-in-the-from-clause-limitation

Comment: You learn something new every day. Answer updated.. Although there must be a nicer way to do this...