# SQL - select rows that have the same value in two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join

The solution to the topic is evading me.

I have a table looking like (beyond other fields that have nothing to do with my question):

NAME,CARDNUMBER,MEMBERTYPE

Now, I want a view that shows rows where the cardnumber AND membertype is identical. Both of these fields are integers. Name is VARCHAR.  Name is not unique, and duplicate cardnumber, membertype should show for the same name, as well.

I.e. if the following was the table:

```
JOHN       | 324   | 2
PETER      | 642   | 1
MARK       | 324   | 2
DIANNA     | 753   | 2
SPIDERMAN  | 642   | 1
JAMIE FOXX | 235   | 6
```

I would want:

```
JOHN       | 324   | 2
MARK       | 324   | 2
PETER      | 642   | 1
SPIDERMAN  | 642   | 1
```

this could just be sorted by cardnumber to make it useful to humans.

What's the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried `select * from <table> where cardnumber = membertype`?

Comment: How are the cardnumber and membertype values of the records that you listed identical? 324 != 2

Comment: Examples clearly show the input and desired output. How is anybody confused?

Comment: We are confused because of the confusing, incorrect wording. Apparently he meant he wants rows where there is a duplicate row based on those 2 fields. That isn't "rows where the cardnumber AND membertype is identical".

Comment: With the examples, you can completely disregard the wording. They speak for themselves.

Comment: Then answer the question. What are you arguing in the comments for?

Comment: >>"With the examples, you can completely disregard the wording." - Maybe on your StackOverflow, not mine. On mine, we read the whole question, including the wording, as do future readers, which is sort of the point of maintaining question quality.

Comment: @mrjoltcola alright, friend. Point taken. Have a nice day.

Comment: I'm sorry my wording has lead to confusion. I don't know how else to put it, but I do also believe the examples speak for themselves.

Comment: That is fine, nobody was criticizing you. We were asking in order to clarify and help. Another member simply questioned why we were confused. I felt the ambiguity was obvious. A more correct wording might have been titled "select duplicate rows based on specific columns".

Comment: @nickdnk What if you had another row, `JAMIE FOXX,235,6` as a duplicate.  Is this possible in your scenario, and would you want it to be shown in the results if it is possible?

Comment: Yes, this should be included too. All cases where there is more than one row containing the same data in both cardnumber and membertype should be included.

This is because there can only be one card of each membertype, but two cards that are not the same type can have the same number.

Comment: Then you need to use @FuzzyTree's answer.  What you are really looking for is duplicate (MEMBERTYPE, CARDNUMBER).

Comment: @Brandon Brah thank you. Your answer works for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you mentioned names can be duplicated, and that a duplicate name still means is a different person and should show up in the result set, we need to use a GROUP BY HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 in order to truly detect dupes.  Then join this back to the main table to get your full result list.

Also since from your comments, it sounds like you are wrapping this into a view, you'll need to separate out the subquery.

```
CREATE VIEW DUP_CARDS
AS
SELECT CARDNUMBER, MEMBERTYPE
FROM mytable t2
GROUP BY CARDNUMBER, MEMBERTYPE
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

CREATE VIEW DUP_ROWS
AS
SELECT t1.*
FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN DUP_CARDS AS DUP
ON (T1.CARDNUMBER = DUP.CARDNUMBER AND T1.MEMBERTYPE = DUP.MEMBERTYPE )
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/37b49)

Comment: What does the t1 and t2 mean after Table? Like a variable for the select command?

Comment: Just table aliases.  Needed when correlating a table to itself in a subquery.  Look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp).

Comment: Thanks. I would accept your answer too, but that doesn't seem possible.

Comment: You can upvote it if you like his answer. I will point out that the answer isn't literally legal, you can't use "table" as a table name. +1 assuming he edits or notes that. Both answers will skip rows that also have identical names, however.

Comment: Edited answer to reflect your thoughts, Mrjoltcola.

Comment: And we don't care about identical names. The identifier is their facebook ID, which is unique. Two people having the same name is no problem.

Answer (score 11):

> What's the most efficient way of doing this?

I believe a `JOIN` will be more efficient than `EXISTS`

```
SELECT t1.* FROM myTable t1
JOIN (
    SELECT cardnumber, membertype
    FROM myTable
    GROUP BY cardnumber, membertype
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2 ON t1.cardnumber = t2.cardnumber AND t1.membertype = t2.membertype
```

Query plan: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0abe3/1

Comment: Sorry, I disagree that this is more efficient.  You've introduced a GROUP BY, although it possibly could depend on the join.  The other would likely be a NESTED LOOP, what would this be?

Comment: @woot the `GROUP BY` query is run once where as the exists subquery is run for each row in the table

Comment: I vote for this as the most correct, given the question, since it includes duplicates where names match, which we must assume is a possibility unless OP tells us he has a unique constraint across all 3 cols.

Comment: True, but only matters of the optimizer isn't doing a nested loop.  Depends on the DBMS, I think.

Comment: All answers will do at least one full table or index scan. The GROUP BY should be doable within a single scan as well.

Comment: Names can be duplicates - doesn't matter and should not be taken into account. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you agree this is better I will change the correct answer. I don't know enough about SQL to make this kind of decision.

Comment: @nickdnk - In that case, this is the more correct answer. The other 2 look for differing name to differentiate the duplicate columns. If this were Oracle, then ROWID, or a simple primary key would be a better fit in the other answers.

Comment: Guys, this is not more efficient than using `exists`.  It uses a `join` with a `group by` aggregate.  View the execution plan and you'll see the difference in the two.  Good answer though.

Comment: He's saying that the name is a facebook id, and therefore unique.  (At least he said so in another comment)

Comment: @sgeddes doing a `dependent subquery` has always been slower for me than joining to a `derived` table where the db could make use of something like a `join buffer`

Comment: @woot I never said the names were facebook IDs. I said each row is identified by facebook ID and that names can be duplicates without problems.

Comment: Sounds like this is the right answer then (although I still don't think it is more efficient, but rather more correct based on the new information).

Comment: Okay. Answer changed. Thanks a lot everyone :)

Comment: I get Views SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause when I try to use this?

Comment: @nickdnk try selecting only from your table. see updated answer

Comment: Makes no difference. We can agree that all I need to change is "mytable" to the name of my table, yes? The columns have correct names.

Comment: @nickdnk it looks like mysql doesn't allow views with subqueries in the from clause. for a workaround see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428641/views-select-contains-a-subquery-in-the-from-clause

Answer (score 10):

You can use `exists` for this:

```
select * 
from yourtable y
where exists (
  select 1
  from yourtable y2 
  where y.name <> y2.name
    and y.cardnumber = y2.cardnumber
    and y.membertype = y2.membertype)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59cbe/2)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to know the **valuepairs** of the 3 fields that are not unique then you could simply do:

```sql
SELECT   concat(NAME, "|", CARDNUMBER, "|", MEMBERTYPE) AS myIdentifier, 
         COUNT(*) AS count
FROM     myTable 
GROUP BY myIdentifier
HAVING   count > 1
```

This will give you all the different pairs of `NAME`, `CARDNUMBER` and `MEMBERTYPE` that are used more than once with a count (how many times they are duplicated). This doesnt give you back the entries, you would have to do that in a second step.