# How to select the name of different column name means heading of the column with the same value in a row of a table?

Tags: mysql, sql

the table would be as below: table name = 'seats' and columns are 'seat1', 'seat2', 'seat3', 'seat4', 'seat5'.

```
id | seat1 | seat2 | seat3 | seat4 | seat5 
 1 |   0   |   1   |   1   |   0   |   1
 2 |   1   |   1   |   0   |   1   |   0
 3 |   1   |   0   |   1   |   1   |   1
```

I need an sql query that provide me the following inquiry. When id = 1 then output will be

```
seat2, seat3, seat5
```

If id = 2, then output will be

```
seat1, seat2, seat4
```

if id = 3 then output will be

```
seat1, seat3, seat4, seat5
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - select rows that have the same value in two columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23860490/sql-select-rows-that-have-the-same-value-in-two-columns)

Comment: No, this is not my query, my query is different columns and many of the columns are same value in the same row of a table. @mayersdesign

Comment: This question is unclear.  What does "detect" mean in this context? Why are the values in single quotes if the columns contain numbers?  You should show sample data *as rows in a table* (hint:  put four spaces before each row).  You should show the results you want the query to return.

Comment: What does it mean `detect 'seat2', 'seat3', 'seat5'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you are looking fetch only seats which are occupied. I have prepared the following query based on that understanding. Please comment if gap in understanding is there :

```
select * from 
(
select 'seat1', seat1 as occupiedStatus from [table]
union
select 'seat2', seat2 as occupiedStatus from [table]
union
select 'seat3', seat3 as occupiedStatus from [table]
union
select 'seat4', seat4 as occupiedStatus from [table]
union
select 'seat5', seat5 as occupiedStatus from [table]
) seatsPivot
where occupiedStatus = 1 ;
```

Comment: Dear Biswabid, please explain 'seatsPivot'. Why is it used?

Comment: can i use here 'AND' operator in where clause? if yes how? I have used but given me an error? as below:
<pre>select * from 
(
select 'seat1', seat1 as occupiedStatus from [table]
union
select 'seat2', seat2 as occupiedStatus from [table]
union
select 'seat3', seat3 as occupiedStatus from [table]
union
select 'seat4', seat4 as occupiedStatus from [table]
union
select 'seat5', seat5 as occupiedStatus from [table]
) seatsPivot
where occupiedStatus = 1 AND id = 67;</pre>

Comment: Id cant be used here..as you are not selecting in the query. you can add it in select then can use in where condition also.

Comment: @ZiaurRahmanShishir which one was the expected answer? 1st answer or my answer? I am confused.

Comment: Certainly yours @Biswabid . I have commented on your answer brother. But I don't know how to give my feedback? please inform me about that, that would be very kind to me.

Answer (score 1):

*Do you mean something like this? If not help me understand and I can adjust the query logic...*

```
  SELECT
        'Occupied Seats = {' +
        CASE WHEN seat1 = 1 THEN '1, ' ELSE '0, ' END +
        CASE WHEN seat2 = 1 THEN '1, ' ELSE '0, ' END +
        CASE WHEN seat3 = 1 THEN '1, ' ELSE '0, ' END +
        CASE WHEN seat4 = 1 THEN '1, ' ELSE '0, ' END +
        CASE WHEN seat5 = 1 THEN '1}' ELSE '0}' END 
    FROM seats 
    WHERE 1 IN (seat1,seat2,seat3,seat4,seat5)
```