# Subquery in mysql VIEW

Tags: mysql

The following SQL Query, when used to create a VIEW is showing the usage of subquery error. This is to fetch the values of a field named CODE from table1 where those values are not present in table2, and also when the Status of those CODE in table2 is not "ASSIGNED" or "SOLD".

```
SELECT S1.CODE
FROM STOCK S1
LEFT JOIN (  
        SELECT t1.CODE
        FROM STOCK t1
        JOIN SALES t2 ON t2.CODE = t1.CODE
        WHERE t2.STATUS IN ('Sold', 'Assigned')) S2 ON S2.CODE = S1.CODE
WHERE S2.CODE IS NULL
```

The SQL query is providing good output, but cannot use this while creating VIEW. Please help me solve this.

Comment: View doesnot allow sub queries. You can create another view and the query from it.

Comment: You can see the question [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428641/views-select-contains-a-subquery-in-the-from-clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good information about [MySQL Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html)

The reason your query wouldn't work is that you *cannot* have a subquery in the FROM clause in MySql **view**.

I couldn't understand your requirement with 100% certainty but it seemed you wanted rows from one table that didn't exist in another or they could exist in another but they couldn't have a certain status. If my understanding of the requirement was right than this query does the same thing. These were the tables I had to work with right now verified this works fine.

**If I'm wrong on the requirement please provide guidance.**

```
/* 
   VIEW: v_testview
   get rows where adminid not in second table
   and rows that are in second table but have
   an email not equal duckduckgo@notgoogle.com    
*/
CREATE VIEW v_testview AS  
  SELECT s.adminid, s.company
  FROM panel_customers s
  WHERE s.adminid NOT IN 
               (SELECT sa.adminid 
                FROM panel_admins sa 
                WHERE sa.email = 'duckduckgo@notgoogle.com')
  AND s.adminid NOT IN 
               (SELECT sa.adminid 
                FROM panel_admins sa);
  .
```

Comment: Thanks.. It worked with some modifications in the condition part.