# QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

In MySQL it works:

```
SELECT * FROM carparks a 
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT * FROM locales_carparks) 
c ON a.carpark_id=c.carpark_id
```

Hot to translate it to JPA:

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM Carparks a LEFT JOIN("
            +"SELECT b FROM a.locales b"
            +")")
```

> IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:
>   ( near line 1, column 72 [SELECT a FROM
>   database.model.carpark.Carparks a LEFT JOIN(SELECT b
>   FROM a.locales b)]

I've simplified example to show the essence of the problem. Normally I use just`SELECT a FROM Carparks a LEFT JOIN a.locales` and it works, but in my case I want to use nested SELECT because my query is much more complex

Comment: Hey, are your entity mapped with a relationship like one to many or so?

Comment: A simple way of writing it would be @Query("Select * from A a  left join B b on a.id=b.id")

Comment: so of course I use relationships, I wanted to simplify it and it is reason why I did not included it. Yup I tried join on a.id=b.id  but with JPA this does not work because JPA recognizes the relationship automatically. 
and the keyword "on"must be omitted

Comment: _the keyword "on"must be omitted_ Why is that ?

Comment: because the ON clause comes from the mapping's join columns and is handled automatically

Comment: Oww, didn't knew that. Never really used those ORM...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a simple alternative

```
create view v_carparks as
    SELECT * FROM carparks a 
    LEFT JOIN  (SELECT * FROM locales_carparks) 
    c ON a.carpark_id=c.carpark_id
```

And use it for the query

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM v_carparks")
```

Especially if the query is complicated, this would be cleaner to have a huge query in a view to hide that complexity.

EDIT :

You can't used a nested query for join. This is written in the [HQL documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries) like this :

> Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses.

This could be explain for the mapping system. Hard to do the mapping with a subqueries result.

Comment: You're right your solution is better but Is it possible to somehow make it work my way?

Comment: @user3871754 Infortunatly, nope. This is in the HQL doc. Let me update my answer

Comment: I tested it, and got : View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: Wait, Hibernate tells you the view can't be called ?

Comment: No I try create view from phpAdmin I think I have to update mySQL to 5.7:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428641/views-select-contains-a-subquery-in-the-from-clause

Comment: @user3871754 Yes, I was about to past the same link .. I didn't new that about MySql, sorry. But you could create a view with the nested query and use it to do the join in the first view ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM Carparks a LEFT JOIN Locales b on a.carpark_id = b.carpark_id")
```

Comment: thanks, I normally use SELECT a FROM Carparks a LEFT JOIN a.locales  and it works, but in my case I wanted to use nested SELECT because my query is much more complex, I am gonna update question to clarify it