# Multiple UNION and JOIN ON

Tags: mysql

How to SELECT rows from multiple tables JOINing on specific key?

I have several tables `states(year)` with same structure. I want to make a VIEW selecting only rows from `states(year)` with propertyid contained in table `properties` under specific user:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW selected_states AS
SELECT *, 2017 AS year FROM states2017
UNION ALL SELECT *, 2018 AS year FROM states2018
AS s
JOIN properties p ON s.propertyID = p.propertyID WHERE p.userID=1
```

getting an error

> The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aca397c

Comment: Why do you want a VIEW?

Comment: I want that VIEW to be used in another query later.

Comment: I would discourage this. MySQL is very poor at optimizing views.

Comment: Anyway, whatever kind of SELECT you want to use, never use `SELECT *`. Instead, always name all the columns you actually want returned - even if that's all of them.

Comment: Additionally, any time you find yourself with enumerated columns, alarm bells should start ringing. Just have a states table, with a year (or any kind of timestamp) column.

Comment: It's a very, very bad idea to have one table per year. (The only exception to this: You have a certain set of years, that will never ever change, so you will never add or remove a year.) Change this to one `states` table with a year column, just as Strawberry suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of

```
SELECT *, 2017 AS year FROM states2017
```

and

```
SELECT *, 2018 AS year FROM states2018
```

are not the same. The last column of the first table is `2017` while that of the second is `2018` so they can't be united.

To fix that create a common alias for the years in both tables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW selected_states AS
SELECT s.*, p.userID FROM
(SELECT states2017.*, '2017' `Year` FROM states2017
UNION ALL 
SELECT states2018.*, '2018' `Year` FROM states2018) s
JOIN properties p ON s.propertyID = p.propertyID WHERE p.userID=1;
```

See a [DEMO on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed45d4/1).

Comment: Getting error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS year FROM states2017 UNION ALL SELECT states2018.*, '2018' `Year` AS year FRO' at line 1. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aca397c/2

Comment: Thanks, marking your response partially correct as regards part starting with "To fix that...". For future visitors, disregard notion that The structure of `SELECT *, 2017 AS year FROM states2017` and `SELECT *, 2018 AS year FROM states2018` are not the same - this is not true, these are the same - see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aca397c/7 (there is no difference if you add apostrophes and delete AS operator from my code).

Comment: Can you come up with a query containing no FROM subqueries? Although your solution works on SQL Fiddle, it does not on my webserver due to lower MySQL version throwing error `View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause` (as discussed on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8428641/views-select-contains-a-subquery-in-the-from-clause)