# View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1349

I have a enquiry about creating view in MySQL workbench. I have error: " View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause" when saving.

This is a copy of my statement:

```
CREATE VIEW viewMorningReport AS 
select z.AllocationDate, z.LocationName, z.StationName, a.00000100, b.01000200, c.02000300  from
(SELECT DISTINCT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName FROM satsschema.employeeslot
where LocationName = 'T2 PML'
and StationName is not null) z
left outer join 
(SELECT AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, EmpName AS '00000100' FROM     satsschema.employeeslot
WHERE Assigned = true
and (EmpTime = '00:00:00' && EmpTime < '01:00:00')) a
on z.LocationName = a.LocationName and z.StationName = a.StationName
left outer join
(SELECT  AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, EmpName AS '01000200' FROM    satsschema.employeeslot
WHERE Assigned = true
and (EmpTime = '01:00:00' && EmpTime < '02:00:00')) b
on a.LocationName = b.LocationName and a.StationName = b.StationName
left outer join
(SELECT  AllocationDate, LocationName, StationName, EmpName AS '02000300' FROM satsschema.employeeslot
WHERE Assigned = true
and (EmpTime = '02:00:00' && EmpTime < '03:00:00')) c
on b.LocationName = c.LocationName and b.StationName = c.StationName
```

Any idea where went wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: View with Subquery in the FROM Clause Limitation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206062/mysql-view-with-subquery-in-the-from-clause-limitation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: View with Subquery in the FROM Clause Limitation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206062/mysql-view-with-subquery-in-the-from-clause-limitation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the official documentation says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-restrictions.html)

> E.4. Restrictions on Views
>
> (..)
>
> Subqueries cannot be used in the FROM clause of a view.

One option could be creating a View for each subquery.
Another one, is modify your view, to avoid `subquerys` in the `from` clause

Answer (score 0):

you can create views of subquery and call him in principal view