# 'GROUP BY' and subquery optimization

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, having

I have two tables: `data` and `img` each raw from `data` having 0, 1 or n images in `img` table.
I want to be able to get all records from `data` having more than 1 images in `img`. Cannot use JOINs because I can not edit the first part of the sql query: `SELECT some_defualt_columns FROM data WHERE`.
Here are my solutions:

**Solution 1** Takes a while to perform but works

```
SELECT some_defualt_columns  FROM data WHERE `id` IN
    (SELECT data_id FROM 
        (SELECT data_id, count(*) as occ FROM 
            img GROUP BY data_id 
            HAVING occ >1)
    AS tmp)
```

**Solution 2** This should be faster than the previous ([MySQL: View with Subquery in the FROM Clause Limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206062/mysql-view-with-subquery-in-the-from-clause-limitation)) but this literally **kills** my MySQL server

```
SELECT *  FROM data WHERE id IN 
    (SELECT data_id FROM img 
         GROUP BY `data_id` 
         HAVING count(`data_id`) > 1)
```

**SOLUTION 3** Maybe the fastes but needs the creation of a view:

```
CREATE VIEW my_data_with_more_than_one_img AS 
    SELECT all_columns_of_data_table FROM 
        data JOIN img 
        GROUP BY img.data_id 
        HAVING (COUNT(img.data_id) > 1
```

Than execute a simple `SELECT` on this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_data_with_more_than_one_img WHERE 1
```

This last solution is rather fast, but I want to know if is there any faster (or smarter) way to get this done

Comment: How many rows do you have in each table, and how long do these queries take to run?

Comment: `img` table has about 81k records and is going to grow much bigger, `data` table has more than 300K records and this too is going to grow. Solution 1: 3,295 total, Query took 0.6065 sec (phpmyadmin data). Solution 3:  3,295 total, Query took 0.6844 sec (phpmyadmin data), but it's much faster to show up in phpmyadmin than solution 1

Comment: In your second solution, you appear to have used different names, and to have used `sagid` for both a table and a column. It would improve the question if you fixed that.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion of the table names: I fixed it now

Comment: If you can't use JOINs because you can't change the outer part of the query, how were you planning to use the view?

Comment: I can save views in the database; it's the php app that manages preview, pagination, forms, etc. that does not accept a custom outer part of the query.