# SQL join clause to return rows with more than one occurrence without grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I want to extract the records which appear more than once from a JOIN query, but without them getting grouped.

Example tables:

```
tbl_names
id    Name
1     Mark
2     John
3     Jane
4     Paul

tbl_locations
id    Location
1     Berlin
2     Frankfurt
2     Stockholm
3     Helsinki
3     Madrid
3     London
4     Paris
```

ID is a foreign key.

Now, the result of the query would be:

```
id     Name    Location
2      John    Frankfurt
2      John    Stockholm
3      Jane    Helsinki
3      Jane    Madrid
3      Jane    London
```

i.e. all JOIN records in which the record in the first table appears more than once in the JOIN clause result.

I can get it grouped of course:

```
SELECT tbl_names.id, tbl_names.Name, tbl_locations.Location FROM tbl_names
 INNER JOIN tbl_locations ON (tbl_names.id = tbl_locations.id)
 GROUP BY tbl_names.id
 HAVING COUNT(tbl_names.id) > 1
```

What I want is to have them not grouped at all. I have tried with a sub-clause and `NOT IN` but it is extremely slow and doesn't give me the results I want.

Any enlightenment will be welcome.

Comment: What is wrong with the results your getting from the grouping query?

Comment: The grouping query returns
    2 John Frankfurt
    3 Jane Helsinki

so basically I can not see all the locations, which is what I wanted in the first place, but only for those which are in more than one location.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this one:

```
SELECT tbl_names.id, tbl_names.Name, tbl_locations.Location
FROM tbl_names
INNER JOIN tbl_locations ON (tbl_names.id = tbl_locations.id)
where tbl_names.id in (select id from tbl_locations
                       group by id having count(*) > 1);
```

This select shows the join you already have, but selects only the names/ids, which have more than 1 entry in the locations table.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/3520552/1741542, this might be faster than a plain subquery:

```
create view view_id_locations as
    select id
    from tbl_locations
    group by id
    having count(*) > 1;

SELECT tbl_names.id, tbl_names.Name, tbl_locations.Location
FROM tbl_names
INNER JOIN tbl_locations ON tbl_names.id = tbl_locations.id
inner join view_id_locations on tbl_names.id = view_id_locations.id;
```

Comment: Thanks Olaf, I just tried that and it gave me what I needed, still slow but it works.

I assume there is no way to do this only with JOIN without using a subclause?

Comment: None that I can think of. But that doesn't mean, it's not possible.

Comment: If performance bothers you, try `explain select` to see where you can add indexes to speed up the query.

Comment: @mendigou Please look at the second solution and see, if it is faster.

Comment: Definitely faster using the view (one the real DB, 49 s for the subquery against 0.1225 s using the view). Thanks a lot!