# MySQL Error Code: 1349. View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create a view but get the following error:

> **View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause**

I am running the following command. I can't seem to figure out how to substitute the nested selects with joins. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
create view student_fee_basic as
select fsbc.*, ffp.name, ffp.amount 'fee'
from
(select sbc.*, ffc.name 'fname', ffc.id 'fid'
    from (select s.admission_no, s.first_name, bc.id 'bid', bc.code, bc.name
        from (select b.id, b.name, c.code
            from batches b, courses c
            where b.name = '2014-2015'
            and b.course_id = c.id) bc
        left join students s on bc.id = s.batch_id) sbc
    left join finance_fee_categories ffc on ffc.batch_id = sbc.bid
    where ffc.name = 'Basic Monthly') fsbc
left join finance_fee_particulars ffp on ffp.finance_fee_category_id = fsbc.fid;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: View with Subquery in the FROM Clause Limitation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206062/mysql-view-with-subquery-in-the-from-clause-limitation)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MySQL does not support subqueries in views:

> Subqueries cannot be used in the FROM clause of a view.

The documentation is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html).

The easiest fix is to use a series of different views for each level.

You can probably rewrite this query to remove the subqueries.  However, I find it very hard to help without explicit joins.

Comment: Great! Thanks! I was able to construct the joins without using nested selects; seems I only needed the confidence that it can be done.

Answer (score 5):

Version 5.7 supports it. 
So one way to fix it is to migrate your database to newer version

Answer (score 0):

upgrade to mysql-8 and your problem is solved.