# Error in creating view

Tags: mysql

I got the error `#1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause`

mycode is:

```
CREATE VIEW `MyViewName` AS
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM (
           (SELECT *
            FROM `crm_clients`
            WHERE ctype=1
            ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,
                                  3)
         UNION
           (SELECT *
            FROM `crm_clients`
            WHERE ctype=1
            ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,
                                  3)
         UNION
           (SELECT *
            FROM `crm_clients`
            WHERE ctype=1
            ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,
                                  3)
         UNION
           (SELECT *
            FROM `crm_clients`
            WHERE ctype=1
            ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,
                                  3)) t
   ORDER BY rand())
```

what is the problem with this code?I am not familier with view

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: View with Subquery in the FROM Clause Limitation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206062/mysql-view-with-subquery-in-the-from-clause-limitation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not allow subqueries in the `from` clause when you define views.

You can do what you want as:

```
Create View `MyViewName` as
    (SELECT * FROM `crm_clients` WHERE ctype=1 order by rand() limit 0,3)
    union 
    (SELECT * FROM `crm_clients` WHERE ctype=1 order by rand() limit 0,3)
    union
    (SELECT * FROM `crm_clients` WHERE ctype=1 order by rand() limit 0,3)
    union
    (SELECT * FROM `crm_clients` WHERE ctype=1 order by rand() limit 0,3)
    order by rand();
```

My guess is that you actually want to change the `ctype` values as well.  Otherwise the query is rather strange.

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html) are the restrictions on views.

Comment: actually ctype different , that's my mistake