# Error in creating view ( View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause) please suggest an alternate option or method for this piece of code

Tags: mysql

I am getting below Error while creating view

> View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

please suggest an alternate option or method for this piece of code

```
Create or Replace view mydb.cnCustomerv
as
Select * from mydb.customermaster 
left join 
(
    Select customertransaction.transactioninvoiceno , customertransaction.transactionvalue , customertransaction.cardnumber from mydb.customertransaction order by customertransaction.transactionid desc limit 1
) as a on 
mydb.customermaster.cardnumber = a.cardnumber
left join
(
    Select customerredemption.transactionuniquecode , customerredemption.redemptionvalue , customerredemption.cardnumber from mydb.customerredemption order by customerredemption.redemptionid desc limit 1
) as B on
mydb.customermaster.cardnumber = B.cardnumber;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206062/mysql-view-with-subquery-in-the-from-clause-limitation  - this may help you, also check second answer by "Json on Linux Apache My" user who describes his problem and looking similar kind of problem.

Comment: @Nilesh on creating view for sub query is not working i have already tried .

Comment: yes creating view on sub query will not work but you can achieve it in other way, check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual, `VIEW` cannot contain subquery. If you want to create a `VIEW` on your query, you need to create a separate views for your sub queries.

First View

```
Create or Replace VIEW mydb.CTView
AS 
Select ct.transactioninvoiceno, ct.transactionvalue, ct.cardnumber 
from mydb.customertransaction ct order by ct.transactionid desc limit 1
```

Second View

```
Create or Replace VIEW mydb.CRView
AS 
Select cr.transactionuniquecode, cr.redemptionvalue, cr.cardnumber 
from mydb.customerredemption cr order by cr.redemptionid desc limit 1
```

Main View,

```
Create or Replace view mydb.cnCustomerv
as
Select * from mydb.customermaster 
left join mydb.CTView as a on mydb.customermaster.cardnumber = a.cardnumber
left join mydb.CRView as B on mydb.customermaster.cardnumber = B.cardnumber;
```

[A view definition is subject to the following restrictions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html): From MySQL Manual

- The SELECT statement cannot contain a subquery in the FROM clause.
- ....

Comment: on executing the mydb.cnCustomerv view the transaction & redemption tables values are not fetched. It shows only customer master details

Comment: Replace your `Select * from mydb.customermaster` with columns you need. e.g. `Select customermaster.*, CTView.transactioninvoiceno, CTView.transactionvalue,CRView.transactionuniquecode, CRView.redemptionvalue from ....`

Comment: No its not working unknown column CTView.transactioninvoiceno in field list

Comment: sorry use `a.` for CTView and `b.` for CRView

Comment: don't tried i use an alternate way :) Thanks a lot @Nilesh