# mysql 5.6 order first then group by

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am using MySQL 5.6, and creating a view. It seems MySQL 5.6 view does not support subquery inside a view. I have two tables like the following:

table 1

`account balance date time in out
408 100.00  2018-03-09  11:36:47        100.00  0.00
408 86.00   2018-03-09  11:54:48        0.00    14.00
408 74.00   2018-03-09  11:54:48        0.00    12.00
408 21.00   2018-03-09  11:54:48        0.00    13.00
408 11.00   2018-03-09  11:54:48        0.00    10.00
408 0.00    2018-03-09  11:54:48        0.00    11.00
408 13000000.00 2018-03-09  19:15:04        13000000.00 0.00
408 12999880.00 2018-03-10  00:51:37            0.00    120.00
408 12999640.00 2018-03-10  00:51:48            0.00    240.00`

table2

```
account name
999 bank1
408 bank2
```

The view is created like this:

```
create view test
select table1.account, table2.name, table1.balance, table1.date from (table1 join table2) where table1.account=table2.account group by table1.account, table1.date
```

The problem is that the view picked out the first time, showed the first balance. But I want the max time on that day. For example, the view results are like:

```
408 bank1 100 2018-03-09
408 bank1 12999880.00 2018-03-10
```

The MySQL 5.6 does not allow me to use a subquery. So is there another way to show the correct balance like this:

```
408 bank1 13000000.00 2018-03-09
408 bank1 12999640.00 2018-03-10
```

which shows the lastest balance of the last record on that day.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: View with Subquery in the FROM Clause Limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206062/mysql-view-with-subquery-in-the-from-clause-limitation)